# Modifying the site root folder only for one view or specific template (django, jquery, html)

Tags: html, jquery, django, jinja2

I am trying to figure it out for several days, I am running out of time.

I would need to make this works without changing the `"<a href='/about'>About Text</a>"` part (please, see code below).

Basically, once the content is parsed, the link will reference to https://www.myhost.com/about, I would need to change that to https://www.myhost.com/something_more/about. I can not change the site root, I would to do it inside this specific view, the HTML template, or the jquery used (if there is a way to do it). I tried different things but without success.

This is the code of the template:

```
<div id="contents"></div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

<script>

  $(document).ready(function () {

      var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");

      $('#contents').append(iframe);
      iframe.contentWindow.document.open();
      iframe.contentWindow.document.write("<a href='/about'>About Text</a>");
      iframe.contentWindow.document.close();

  });

</script>
```

This is the view:

```
def this_view(request):
    return render(request, 'my_app/this_view.html')
```

Thank you, I appreciate any help.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do. You want to change the href of a link, but you specifically don't want to change the line that adds the href? Would it work to include a parameter from the view and have an if-else in your jquery that chooses the href based on the parameter?

Comment: Thank you for answering. Exactly because in the real scenario it is not text written by me in the view, it is an HTML content of an external webpage retrieved by API or another view. That page has all ref with the "/" at the beginning. So, I prefer to not replace the "/" in there because of the different types of URL references (href, src, etc). It was then when I thought that maybe changing the root site folder only for this template I could accomplish to append this additional folder path. I hope to be clear with the explanation.

Comment: Where you store the template doesn't have anything to do with what the URL is. The href "/about" will always take someone to <current_page_url>/about.

Comment: Hello @user984003, maybe I wrote something wrong or you answered fast. I believe that is wrong. Since what I know "/about" is an absolute path, so, the final URL always will be "mydomain/about". The case you showed could be true if instead of "/about" is used "about". So, practically my question was how to append any sub-path between the domain and one absolute path without replacing the whole text inside the html page. I agree the location of the template has nothing to do with this ( I never said that, unless my English said that by mistake) neither the location of the view.

Comment: @user984003 So, in some point the client browser takes the content of the page and append the domain to all absolute paths. I do not know if there is any variable We can inject to change this bahavior and append something in the middle. Thank you, I appreciate it.

Comment: The browser creates the link based on the URL. So, if you use "/whatever" the browser will get the actual domain and append the /whatever. The domain is in the page/URL. It's not some  variable that you tell the browser.

Comment: Thank you @user984003, that was my real question. If it was any chance to tell the browser to append some path in the middle. I appreciate it. Learning day after day :-)

Comment: You're welcome. You'd need to change the actual href. You can either include a variable from the server/template or include javascript that changes the href based on something. Of course, that requires that you have access to change the page.